# Apache geode gemfire pulse

Tags: gemfire, geode

We are using Spring data gemfire, we are planning to migrate to Apache geode latest version. In the VMWare gemfire version we had to explicitly set the path of the gemfire installable for the pulse to work properly. If we are using Apache geode jar, will we able to get the pulse up and running without specifying the installable location.

We are not using gfsh in our project, we want to ensure that we have minimal dependency on the installable version when we upgrade gemfire.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `GEODE_HOME` environment variable when using `spring-boot-data-geode`, you just need to make sure the correct dependencies are within the classpath of your application (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-manager-applications) for more details).
I've written a very basic example showing how to start a `Locator` with the Pulse application embedded, you can find it [here](https://github.com/jujoramos/stackoverflow/tree/main/sbdg-embedded-pulse-68026350)

As a side note, and regarding the following:

> We are using Spring data gemfire, we are planning to migrate to Apache geode latest version.

In order to avoid weird and hard to fix runtime issues, please always make sure to use a combination of versions fully supported in the [Spring Boot for Apache Geode and VMware Tanzu GemFire Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix)

Answer (score -1):

After going through various answers and documentations I was able to start pulse by the help of following article.

[Start Gemfire Pulse](https://echnolo.com/how-to-start-gemfire-geode-pulse-from-spring-boot/)